# SVG cover parent

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I created a svg tag using this command:

```
var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var elem = document.createElementNS(NS, "svg");
elem.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
elem.setAttribute("width", "100%");
elem.setAttribute("height", "100%");
parent = document.getElementById("parent");
parent.appendChild(elem);
```

CSS:

```
div.parent {
            width:500px;
            height:1000px;
            border:solid 1px black;
            border-radius:10px;
            margin:50px;
            background:radial-gradient(circle,white 95%,silver);
            box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent" class="parent"></div>
```

But this svg did not cover entire space of it's parent, Why?
Please help me, Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? Because in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxMarkson/xLkf2/5/) seems all working properly

Comment: @MaxMarkson: Please review this fiddle, as you can see the svg did not cover it's parent: http://jsfiddle.net/xLkf2/6/

Comment: Well, if you use `var r = rect(100, 50, "blue");` I think it's logic the rect doesn't cover the entire parent, if you use the correct size for the blue rectangle you'll see the entire parent covered

Comment: @MaxMarkson: I want to the **SVG** covers it's parent NOT **rect**

Comment: Yes, it's obvious but if the rect inside the svg fill the div then it obviously that EVEN the svg cover the entire parent. If not the rect will not cover the parent.

Comment: For example look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxMarkson/xLkf2/8/). You'll se two square, the blue one on top-left, the red one on bottom-right. If you modify the size of the `elem` object (try with `width:50%`) the red one will disappear. That means the svg is covering the entire div, after the modify the svg will not cover the div for entire anymore and the square disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the parent needs to have a height specified, if you want it to be 100%, the parent nodes will have to have 100% set to them too. if you want it to fill the screen, set html,body to 100% height and the child nodes as well.

have a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/xLkf2/1/

```
.parent{width:200px; height:200px; background:grey;}
```

Comment: It seems my svg has width and height 0 in your fiddle

Comment: Hey! in chrome, inspecting the element i get 100% w and height. What browser are you using?

Comment: strange, in firefox it appears to be the size of the drawing: http://jsfiddle.net/xLkf2/7/

Comment: so you can draw a box inside the container and it will be 100%

Answer (score 1):

Set your viewBox attribute to the size of your content.  Note that percentage values are not allowed in a viewBox.  Also note that viewBox is case-sensitive - it has a upper-case 'B'.

So if your content occupies the area from 0,0 to 300,200, the SVG element should look like:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 200">
```

The SVG should then be scaled to fill its container.  Or, more accurately, it will be scaled up so that it fits inside the container but keeps it's aspect ratio.  If your container is a different shape (aspect ratio) and you want it to be stretched horizontally and vertically to fit exactly, then use:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 200" preservAspectRatio="none">
```

I have modified your example to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/du5tg/1/

Comment: Thanks for response, i think this is a bug for Firefox and as it seems there is no way to solve this problem, Also percentage values is okay in viewBox property, Thanks again

Comment: Sorry. You are incorrect. Percentage values are only valid for values of type "Length".  The viewBox attribute is defined as "The value of the ‘viewBox’ attribute is a list of four numbers...".

Comment: My version of the fiddle works fine in FF22, so I don't know what you mean.